# b'no arguments in initialization list' Choroplet folium

Tags: python, geopandas, folium, choropleth

Anyone could help me, I got the next code

```py
    mymap = folium.Map(location=[4.651751,-74.099199],zoom_start=12, tiles="OpenStreetMap", 
    min_zoom=11,max_zoom=14)
    folium.Choropleth(geo_data=upz_bogota_hurtos,
                          name="Choroplet",
                          data=upz_bogota_hurtos,
                          columns=["UPlNombre","Cantidad"],
                          key_on="features.properties.UPlNombre",
                          fill_color="YlGn",
                          fill_opacity=1,
                          line_opacity=0.2,
                          legend_name='Cantidad de hurtos a personas'
                          ).add_to(mymap)
mymap
```

error : `b'no arguments in initialization list'`
upz_bogota_hurtos is a GeoPandas Dataframe.
Thanks in advance for your worthy help.

Here the shape file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qS26szkaz0W7u-c603mJ3PhQythfsWmS/view?usp=sharing

here the data frame to fill the Choropleth https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VN13zSnFCZ3gNLPB2nE26G5Y0lwGkFl2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: The files have been uploaded,  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is the `upz_bogota_hurtos` file?

Comment: Is the result of merging the upz_Bogota and df_grouped, the ide is to work the Choropleth over a Geo Dataframe in order to simplify the `key_on` feature. `upz_Bogota_hurtos = upz_Bogota.merge(df_grouped, on="UPlNombre", how="outer"` the idea is to give a value of 0 where there is not coincidence.

Comment: Thank's so much stack overflow, I can fix the issue, it wasn't because of the community help but, people who can reach this post i will come in handy. I had reinstall `Geopandas` and assure that `pyproj` version was 2.2.1 os higher, that's all.